# HTML5 banner not showing correctly in Revive Adserver

Tags: wordpress, advertising

I want to insert an HTML5 banner on our Reviver Adserver (version 3.2.2). Here's what I did :

1. Created a new banner;
2. Selected 'Generic HTML banner' from the dropdown menu;
3. Copied the ad's HTML code;
4. Pasted it in the text input area;
5. In the 'Alter HTML to enable click tracking for' dropdown, I selected Revive AdServer;
6. Enabled the 'This banner can be safely displayed inside an iframe (e.g. is not expandable)' option
7. Entered the size of the banner;
8. And finally, saved everything.

When I try to open the webpage where the banner should appear, the `iframe` is there, but it is showing nothing at all.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Revive AdServer has a number of [troubleshooting steps](https://www.revive-adserver.com/faq/troubleshooting-banner-delivery/) that you can follow if the ad isn't showing on your site, some of they key ones are...

- Try adding the client code to a blank HTML page as some of your HTML, javascript, or CSS may be interfering with the showing of a given ad or ad unit.
- Try waiting for up to 20 minutes. There is a delivery cache for active servers.
- Check the zones probability tab as this will tell you what banners are ecpected to be used and how often.